# Matlab Insert NaN into array

Tags: matlab, nan

I need to insert NaNs into in specific positions of an array.
I wrote the code that is correctly doing it, but as I need to do it for really large arrays, it's taking too long to run. Numpy has the function `insert(i, x)` that inserts an item at a given position. Is there a similar function in Matlab? Or is there a more efficient way to do it?

```
a = [1 2 3 5 6 7 9 10 13 14];
insertNanIndex = [0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0];

for i = find(insertNanIndex)
    a = [a(1:i-1), NaN, a(i:end)]
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The efficient way to do this would be to pre-compute the size of the result, make sure that `insertNanIndex` was large enough to serve as a mask, and insert `a` into the correct indices all at once. Right now, you are literally re-allocating the entire array for every NaN. Numpy's `insert` function would be equally inefficient because it would be doing the same operation.

If, as in your example, the number of zeros matches the number of elements of `a`, you can allocate an array based on `insertNanIndex` and mask it directly:

```
result = nan(size(insertNanIndex));
result(~insertNanIndex) = a;
```

If the number of zeros in `insertNanIndex` is not equal to the size of `a`, you can pad or trim it, but in that case, it becomes more of a moot point as to what the whole thing means.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm getting the following error on the last line: ```Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides have a different number of
elements.```

Comment: Great! Thank you.